# nested css values in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, css, reportviewer

I have the following in my Site.css file for normal formatting:

```
input, textarea {
    border: 1px solid #e2e2e2;
    background: #fff;
    color: #333;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    margin: 5px 0 6px 0;
    padding: 5px;
    width: 300px;
}
```

Then I have a reportViewer control which contains textareas and due to the css above it looks wrong.
For that I need to set:

```
input, textarea {
}
```

How can I have both code sections in the same css file or how can I tell the reportViewer control to ignore any css styling from the Site.css file?

asx code:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">

    <div runat="server" class="reportViewer-wrapper">
        <rsweb:ReportViewer ID="rptViewer" runat="server" Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="8pt" Width="100%" Height="1000px" ProcessingMode="Remote" WaitMessageFont-Names="Verdana" WaitMessageFont-Size="14pt">
        <ServerReport ReportPath="/Reports/Tracking" ReportServerUrl="http://srv/ReportServer" />
        </rsweb:ReportViewer>
    </div>
</asp:Content>
```

CSS:

```
.reportViewer-wrapper input, .reportViewer-wrapper textarea {
     /* needs to be blank - default settings*/ 
}

.reportViewer-wrapper td {
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    border: 0 none;
}
```

Comment: Create a new class...

Comment: I did, but the top css code overwrites that. If I could only change the input, textarea values in the class it would be perfect

Comment: Hence the cascading part :), can you post your updated CSS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your rules are very general and you should probably make them a bit more specific e.g. by addressing a certain class.

To give an example, wrap your ReportViewer into a div

```
<div class="reportViewer-wrapper">....</div>
```

and reset your input and textarea for that clas

```
.reportViewer-wrapper input, .reportViewer-wrapper textarea {
     /* whatever styles you need */ 
}
```

Comment: That makes sense. But it won't let me add the reportViewer to div for some reason. `Content ('</div>') does not match any properties within a 'Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportViewer', make sure it is well-formed.`

Comment: Maybe you can post more comment so we can give you a better example/explanation.

Comment: Also if [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.reporting.webforms.reportviewer_properties%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) is the ReportViewer-control you're using, it has a CssClass-Property. You can set that and then modify your stylesheet accordingly.

Comment: It's ok it was a typo in the code. But it did not work, it still inherited the `input, textarea { ... }` values.

Comment: Yeah you would have to overwrite every one of them. `input { }` does not remove any styles.
It might be easier in your case to alter your stylesheet and only apply the styles to specific elements instead of making it a general rule. But that depends on how your project.

Comment: Yes it will still inherit them because of the `cascading` nature of `CSS` - you will need to override them in your `class`.

Comment: ok that makes sense. How would I overwrite `width: 300px` but without giving it a value? the problem is that applies to the calendar icon of the report so I don't really want to give it a size.

Comment: You could try `width:auto`

Answer (score 1):

Cascade Stylying Sheets are cascading...this means that you can override things. So that last thing you tell is what it will do.

This to tell you that you can use a class to override the textareas in the control.

for example you could do something like this:

```
input, textarea {
    border: 1px solid #e2e2e2;
    background: #fff;
    color: #333;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    margin: 5px 0 6px 0;
    padding: 5px;
    width: 300px;
}

.reportViewerX {
    /* New Styles */
}
```

This would mean that just the textarea with the class reportViewerX would have the new styles. All the others would remain with same has before.

**UPDATE:**

Has per comments and answer from boldty I should add some explanation.

Wrap your control on a div and add a class to that div like so:

```
<div class="reportViewerX">
    <YOUR CONTROL>
</div>
```

Then in the CSS add this after the general one:

```
.reportViewerX input, .reportViewerX textarea {
        border: 5px solid #000000;
        background: #000011;
        color: #222;
        font-size: 1.1em;
        margin: 10px 0 6px 0;
        padding: 3px;
        width: auto;
}
```

Enter values that you want, I just typed random values.